# Previous rows are replacing with new rows while calling 'notifydatasetchanged' in listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to add some new rows to a `custom listview` by `clicking` a `button`. My every row contains an `EditText`. My need is to create new rows while `clicking` on the `Button` each time. I made it successfully, but the problem am facing here is, while am `clicking` the `Button`, a new row will be created but it's refreshing the whole custom `listview` and it's replace everything that I wrote in `EditText` with empty **(it's creating some new `EditText`).** I don't need to happen that. I need to preserve the whole data what I wrote in the `EditText` even after a new row is created.

> Here is my code with calls the `adapter`:

```
final RequestAttributeAdapter adapter = new RequestAttributeAdapter(context,listItems);
    lv_Attribute.setAdapter(adapter);
    tvAddAttribute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listItems.add("1");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

> Here is my `adapter class`:

```
private ArrayList<String> attributes;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public RequestAttributeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return attributes.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "ViewHolder"})
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_attribute_list,null);
    FloatingEditText ftName = (FloatingEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etAttrName);
    TextView attributeNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.attributeNumber);
    attributeNumber.setText("Attribute : "+(position+1));
    //CheckBox cbRequired = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbRequired);

    //cbRequired.setChecked(attributes.get(position).isRequired());
    //ftName.setText(attributes.get(position).getAttribute_name());
    if (position>0)
        ftName.requestFocus();

    ftName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //attributes.get(position).setAttribute_name(editable.toString());
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: You need to save data of `EditText` into `ArrayList`  according  to their `positions` and in `getView()` get data from `ArrayList` and `setText()`  to `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. @sukhbir

Comment: Your Welcome @Rahul  . Does it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible by using `notifyDataSetChanged()` function, but you can try this https://android.jlelse.eu/smart-way-to-update-recyclerview-using-diffutil-345941a160e0

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this By saving data of `EditText` into `ArrayList` according to their positions and in `getView()` get data from `ArrayList` and `setText()` to `EditText`

**Hope this will help**